# PHP: Count-IF for Arrays

Tags: php, arrays

What would be the most efficient way of counting the number of times a value appears inside an array?

Example Array ('apple','apple','banana','banana','kiwi')

**Ultimately I want a function to spit out the percentages for charting purposes
 (e.g. apple = 40%, banana = 40%, kiwi = 20%)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put it through [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php). The percentages should be easy...

```
$countedArray = array_count_values($array);
$total = count($countedArray);

foreach ($countedArray as &$number) {
    $number = ($number * 100 / $total) . '%';
}
```

Comment: +1 and then use `counts['apple']*100/count($array)` to get percentage!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`array_count_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php):

> ```
> <?php
> $array = array(1, "hello", 1, "world", "hello");
> print_r(array_count_values($array));
> ?>
> ```
>
> The above example will output:
>
> ```
> Array
> (
>     [1] => 2
>     [hello] => 2
>     [world] => 1
> )
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = Array ('apple','apple','banana','banana','kiwi');
$b = array_count_values($a);
function get_percentage($b,$a){
    $a_count = count($a);
    foreach ($b as $k => $v){
        $ret[$k] = $v/$a_count*100."%";
    }
    return $ret;
}
$c = get_percentage($b,$a);
print_r($c);
```